# How to make a cell higher in matplotlib using the plt.table function?

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following code uses `colwidths` to adjust the cell's width:

```
import matplotlib as  mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mpl.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = ['FangSong']
mpl.rcParams['axes.unicode_minus'] = False

labels = ['A难度水平', 'B难度水平', 'C难度水平', 'D难度水平']
students = [0.35, 0.15, 0.2, 0.3]
explode = [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]
colors = ['r', 'y', 'b', 'gray']

plt.pie(students, autopct='%3.1f%%',
        labels=labels, textprops={'fontsize': 12,
                                  'family': 'FangSong',
                                  'fontweight': 'bold'},
        explode=explode, colors=colors)

studentValues = [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], [350, 150, 200, 300], ['test', 'test', 'test', 'test']]
cellcolors = [['r', 'y', 'b', 'gray'], ['b', 'gray', 'y', 'r'], ['gray', 'y', 'b', 'r']]
rowLabels = ['aaaaa','bbbbb','ccccc']
plt.table(cellText=studentValues,
          cellColours=cellcolors,
          cellLoc='center', colWidths=[0.1] * 4,
          rowLabels=rowLabels)
plt.show()
```

How could I adjust the height of the cell inside the `plt.table` function?

Comment: Did you manage to get what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Save the link to: plt.table. And adjust via 'scale'.

```
ytable = plt.table(cellText=studentValues,
          cellColours=cellcolors,
          cellLoc='center', colWidths=[0.1] * 4,
          rowLabels=rowLabels)

ytable.scale(1, 1.0)
```